# How to properly serve a Django application throught Twisted's Web server?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, twisted, wsgi

I am building a system that was some components that will be run in its own process or thread. They need to communicate with each other. One of those components is a Django application, the internal communication with the Django app will not be done through HTTP. Looking for networking libraries I found Twisted (awesome library!), reading its documentation I found that Twisted [implements the WSGI specification](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html) too, so I thought its [Web server](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html) could serve WSGI applications like Django. Following the docs I come with the following script to serve the Django app:

```py
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.python.threadpool import ThreadPool
from mysite.wsgi import application as django_application

# Create and start a thread pool to handle incoming HTTP requests
djangoweb_threadpool = ThreadPool()
djangoweb_threadpool.start()
# Cleanup the threads when Twisted stops
reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'shutdown', djangoweb_threadpool.stop)

# Setup a twisted Service that will run the Django web app
djangoweb_request_handler = server.Site(WSGIResource(reactor, djangoweb_threadpool, django_application))
djangoweb_server = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8000)
djangoweb_server.listen(djangoweb_request_handler)

reactor.run()
```

Save it in a file like `runserver.py` in the same directory of `manage.py`, you can start the WSGI server by running `python runserver.py`.
I made a django view that does a blocking call to `time.sleep()` to test it, it worked fine. Since it's multithread, it did not block other requests. So I think it works well with the synchronous Django code. I could setup another service with a custom protocol as a gateway for internal communication.
1) Does that script properly loads the Django app? It will work the same way as other WSGI servers like gunicorn and uwsgi?
2) Will that threads be run in parallel?

Comment: You could use daphne to serve your app if you are using Django 3, it uses twisted. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/asgi/daphne/

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for the comment. I liked Twisted because it treats Web as a simple network resource, it has a beautiful abstraction that allows you to build a network application as a set of distinct network resources. Is Daphne coupled to the Web standards? How can I implement a custom protocol to be served?

Answer (score 0):

[`hendrix`](https://github.com/hendrix/hendrix) is a project that lets you run django via twisted. It looks like it can run other twisted services if desired (https://hendrix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying-other-services/).

If you're in the early stages of developement, consider [`klein`](https://github.com/twisted/klein). It's more akin to flask than django though.